# I can't get Zoom API Key

Tags: web-services, web-applications, arabic, zoom-sdk

I'm trying to get Zoom API Key. So I tried to go to the marketplace.zoom.us page, but I get a blank page. It seems that this problem exists in certain countries, including the Arab countries. I tried several browsers but the same problem, it shows me a blank page. This problem seems new. Because before, I was able to access this page and get the Zoom API Key. Did you try to access this page from an Arab country, and did you face the same problem?
The page appears on mobile, but the mobile version does not provide access to the Zoom API Key.
I need to get Zoom API Key in order to link my website to Zoom. But I can't access the marketplace.zoom.us page. Is there another way to get Zoom API Key?

Comment: https://marketplace.zoom.us/ works fine for me. Please reformulate your question to explain in more details what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine , try creating a new zoom account and then create a jwt app.
Or try using VPN instead.

https://github.com/MalikHamzaJaved/ZoomClient
you can only use my zoomapi client , complete api integrated in .net standard